# Why does Visual Studio incorrectly show errors in intellisense, but not build?

Tags: c#, syntax-error, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have a class named `Strings` which has some const strings. I am referencing these consts from another class named `TestScript1`.

Both `Strings` and `TestScript1` are in the same project.

Intellisense is reporting an error when I access the consts from `Strings` in `TestScript1` as shown in the following image:

[image]

However, if I compile and run the project, everything works fine - no compile errors, no runtime exceptions. Furthermore, if I change the error window to show "Build Only" errors, no errors appear on build, but I still see the squiggly red underlines.

Things I've tried:

- Including the fully-qualified name instead of a using.
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Deleting the .suo file in the .vs folder
- Clean and Rebuild

Is there anything I can do to get Visual Studio's intellisense to realize that this is not in fact a compile error?

Update 1: Here's some more details and things I've tried.

The `Storyvania.DataTypes` namespace contains 5 other classes. Those all show up just fine in intellisense, it's just the Strings class.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.4.1.

The problem I'm experiencing is not only a syntax error but the dropdown that appears when typing does not recognize the `Strings` class.

I've also tried (to no avail):

- Changing the `const` strings to `static`
- Changing the `Strings` class to itself being `static`
- Making the `Strings` class `public` (it shouldn't matter because they're in the same project, but I tried it anyway)
- I mentioned it above but in case it wasn't clear, I tried accessing the fully-qualified `Storyvania.DataTypes.Strings` rather than just `Strings` with a `using` statement.
- Restarting Visual Studio after all of the above.

Comment: The error is probably showing because you're accessing that class as if it were static. Since you only use it statically you can make it explicitly static and the error should go away.

Comment: Microsoft has been trying to make IntelliSense work the same way as the compiler (they are now all powered by Roslyn). However, like you discovered there are still remaining issues, and if you cannot get used to it, disable IntelliSense would be the only way to get rid of such false alarms.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it - as you can see in the screen shot, the error is on `Strings` and not on a member of `Strings`. Visual Studio doesn't even bring up "Strings" in the intellisense dropdown.

Comment: That appears to be a generated file `Strings.Generated.cs`.  It seems like Intellisense is having trouble with the namespace;  Do you have another file that has a `Storyvania.DataTypes` namespace? Does the error go away if you explicitly use `Storyvania.DataTypes.Strings`?

Comment: also, does the problem go away if you set the `class Strings` to `public`?

Comment: Yes it is a generated file. The `Storyvania.DataTypes`namespace (and matching folder) has 5 other files/classes, all of which can be accessed just fine. I'll add details to an edit.

Comment: @VictorChelaru, please have a try with the following steps to troubleshot this issue 1: Create a new method under Class TestScript1 to test, 2: create a new class to invoke the Strings, 3: re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator and click ‘Update’ to upgrade to VS 15.4.4 version.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2019 also has the problem. It seems that VS fails to clear/update some of the data they cache. Try deleting folders named `.vs` from root of your repository/solution and its subfolders.

Comment: Thank you, @zendu, your answer saved my day. I didn't know, that Intellisense in VS caches stuff in .vs. My problem was, that Intellisense still showed the warnings that I suppressed in the project settings. I even restarted VS. Only after deleting the .vs folder, the intellisense got synchronised with the project settings.